# Prism: the default xml namespace of the project must be the msbuild xml namespace

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, prism

I am trying to access the example prism projects that you can find here: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf

However, after downloading the repository and trying to open any of the examples, I am getting this error:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions to try and solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more research I found a solution to my problem, I had to download the latest version of the dotnet SDKs. You can find the link I used here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0

I also needed to open up my project in VS 2019, as 2015 still was not working.

Comment: The VS updater when changing versions of VS often fails.  After a failure occurs you will get errors like you are getting because the  version or libraries in the csproj file doesn't match the version of Net installed.  The .csproj is text and can be edited to solve these issues by changing version numbers. You can create a new project and then do SaveAll.Copy all the source files from old project to new project.  Then using VS menu "Project:Add Existing Item" add the source files to the new project.  Then compile.If you are still having issue in old project Solution Explorer check references.